# Network Service Permissions for root directory Azure

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-web-roles

I want to give the network service account modify permission (root project directory) on start of my Azure webrole, anyone know of a way of doing this? After modification, I would reset this value to keep things secure. Primary purpose is I need to modify the webconfig to change wcf addresses based upon staging/production environment differences, on multiple nodes.

I have tested the routine and it will properly run once permissions are given to the network service account. I wouldn't mind if it was a first-launch modification, but unfortunately directory permissions change upon deployment of a new version, as it swaps VHD's on which the sites reside...

Any help would be awesome...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you objective is to update web.config to add/modify setting related to your Azure environment, you can do that using Web Administration module by adding proper code to Role Startup() routine. I believe this way you will have an easier and clean solution.

The process is defined in [this blog](http://blog.elastacloud.com/2011/05/13/azure-howto-programmatically-modify-web-config-on-webrole-startup/) and there may be others who may have much better ways to do it.

Comment: Yes, I looked into that, unfortunately I couldn't find much more info on it, and this blog is old so the source file is no longer available, and I could not get GetWebConfiguration to load up the config for edit, so I ended up looking for another solution. Guess I'll play around with it a bit more and see if I can get it to work.